# Expection of product of conditioned and unconditioned random variable

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

Given are three random variables $X, Y, Z$.

If I now want to calculate e.g. 
$$ \text{E}\left[Z\cdot \left(Y\middle|X=x\right)\right], $$

does 
$$ \text{E}\left[Z\cdot \left(Y\middle|X=x\right)\right]= \text{E}\left[Z\cdot Y\middle|X=x\right] $$
hold?

My guess is yes, since - assuming that $X=x$ contains information about $Z$ (i.e.  not independent) - it would be kind of strange to have the information that $X=x$ "available" for $Y$, but not for $Z$, right?

Comment: Formally, what do you mean by $Z\cdot (Y\mid X = x)$ and how does this differ from $Z\cdot Y \mid X = x$?

Comment: Well, $Z \cdot (Y|X=x)$ is the product of the random variables $Z$ and $Y|X=x$, which you get when you incorporate the knowledge that $X=x$. $Z\cdot Y|X=x$ (or $(Z\cdot Y)|X=x$) on the other hand is the product of $X\cdot Z$, **given** that $X=x$.

Comment: I cannot differentiate between the two formulations in your comment. Either you have the information of $x = X(\omega)$ or you do not and the expressions are the same as you expected in your question. I would say that $Z\cdot (Y\mid X = x)$ is abuse of notation - how would you write the probability distribution? "$P(Z\cdot (Y\mid X = X(\omega)) \in \cdot )$"?

Comment: Sorry for not responding with an explicit "yes" or "no"! I do not feel competent enough to do so!